# Gruntjs task issues

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

i got couple of problem with gruntJS
I want to combine my js and css files in a files for example: all.js and all.css (this was just example) using grunt-concat

but prompt gaves me this error:
[image]

i thought maybe because of this I couldn't create my task and my codes are below:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
 
   grunt.initConfig({
     concat: {
    js: {
      src: ['js/1.js', 'js/2.js'],
      dest: 'build/scripts.js',
    },
    css: {
      src: ['css/main.css', 'css/screen.css'],
      dest: 'build/css/styles.css',
    },
  },
});
 
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
};
```

whenever i wrote grunt concat it throw me editor.

Answer (score 1):

They are not error. They are warning because your project, named first, does not have "description", "repository" and README.

The first two are meta information that should be written in package.json.
The third is a missing README file.

You can fix them or simply ignore them.